How did twilio achieve setting this feature of sending bulk messages from a users number
Twilio has "Bring Your Own Number" policy where a user can register his number to twilio and can send whatsapp text messages on Whatsapp to his contacts programically. How did twilio achieve this
Had some ideas but wanted to know how twilio did it

Twilio is registered as an official partner with Meta, which allows different privileges to ordinary users.
To register your number as a WhatsApp sender, simply ensure that the number is on a device that allows you to receive the SMS or call authentication code
https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/self-sign-up
